# Flutter Android apk is not able to install in device after the apk bundle release

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, android-install-apk

I was trying to install the apk but I can't. First I release the apk which was working fine and then I was trying to install apk in my device

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.fluttergenerateapk"
            minSdkVersion 28
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: uninstall your old pp and try again.If they are on same version it wont install

Comment: @griffins This is the first time I am trying to install this app. It should work in other phone but it is not working

Comment: Make sure your sign config is ok by typing. `adb install pathTo/apk.apk` then see what abd will tell you